# Why query takes indefinite amount of time to execute in certain date range?

Tags: sql, postgresql, greenplum

I have a query that I'm trying to execute and when I take certain range, for example, 7th week of 2022, it never executes, but when I'm running query for the same week in previous year it executes well. What could be the reason of such behaviour?

It seems that it goes like that in all date ranges of February 2022.

Comment: I assume you mean it never completes, rather than never executes? Please update your question with the SQL and the EXPLAIN PLAN for the 2 versions of the query

Comment: ANALYZE the involved tables.

Comment: Is there data with dates in February 2022?

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add the [execution plan](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/using-explain.html) generated using **`explain (analyze, buffers, format text)`** (_not_ just a "simple" explain) as  [formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) and make sure you preserve the indention of the plan. Paste the text, then put `\`\`\`` on the line before the plan and on a line after the plan. Please also include complete `create index` statements for all indexes as well.

Comment: We need to see the query as well as the table and index definitions. Otherwise we are just guessing.

Answer (score 0):

May be previous year has less data so the related partition returned the result quickly.

Answer (score 0):

check on the segment host, is the segment process busy, maybe try pstack the query process and see what its doing